# How to set the access token with the Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am searching for something similar to what `Facebook::setAccessToken($access_token)` does in the PHP SDK ; that is, set the access token used for subsequent requests (having retrieved it by other means).

In the Javascript one, I can only find the getter (`FB.getAccessToken`). I imagine this has been made on purpose to avoid using the access token client-side, but what are the risks if only the user related to the access token can see it ?

I could embed it as a parameter for each query, but this is impossible for XFBML as far as I know.

Any idea ?

Comment: Why do you need to set the access token yourself?

Comment: I have the same problem. I need to set it myself because I logged the user in via OAuth and have the access token stored in the session, but now I need to display a page to let them select a picture from Facebook.

Comment: @CBroe In my case, I wanted the JS SDK to use a page access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built-in in the SDK.

If you really needed it, you could hack it this way:

```
FB.provide('', {
  'setAccessToken': function(a) {
    this._authResponse = { 'accessToken': a };
  }
});
// Usage
FB.setAccessToken('my_access_token');
```

But if you do this, Facebook will log to their server that you use a "deprecated" function of their SDK and send you a warning message.
Better pass it to the requests directly (this is what I ended up to).

That does not work for XFBML though (you will have to issue FQL queries yourself and populate your own markup).

Comment: FB.provide is not a function