# Facebook API passing access token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get some user info like first name and last name using the Facebook JavaScript SDK. I have an access token but users are not logged in in my app. Is it possible to get the user info using the access token?

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=<token>`

Comment: Ok, so use the graph API, I was hoping for something in the form of FB.api('/me' )

Comment: The same principle applies to the SDK. You can pass the token as `FB.api('/me?access_token=<token>' , callback)` or follow this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12949402/2151050

Answer (score 2):

This would be the proper way to use the API:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'first_name,last_name', access_token: 'xxx'}, (response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```